# How to minimize OpenCv library size?

Tags: opencv, android-ndk

I'm looking to minimize the size of my android ndk built library.

I have started with the pre-built OpenCv libraries for Android and as of now the size of my lib is about 3MB. How can I minimize it's size?

I only need read/write files capability, png encode/decode, jpeg decoder and the typical image manipulation functions from OpenCv such as resize and cvtColor.

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking to minimize the library by stripping out those components of the library that you will not use? If so, it'll be quite a long drawn process with multiple build cycles while you strip down the library.

Comment: Well it seemed like you could specify flags at build time.  Similar to methods used by ffmpeg.

Comment: You could also manually comment out those sections of the library source that you are sure you wont need, which leads to the multiple build cycles that I mentioned earlier. However it is a dicey route. Better to use the flags instead, as you mentioned.

Comment: Build your opencv. Use the cmake-gui to configure the project, and disable as much as you can. However, you might want to enable tbb for speed reasons. Remember to remove the debug symbols.

Answer (score 4):

You've probably moved on with your project by now, Jona, but others not using the cmake-gui may like a command-line example. i.e. if you didn't want the CCALIB module, you could build like this:

cmake -DBUILD_OPENCV_CCALIB=OFF [other cmake flags] ../

Manipulating build flags may not cover all the module exclusions you would like, however, it's probably a good place to start. To see the list of flag options, open CMakeLists.txt file (top of the opencv source directory).

Turning on/off flags also won't break your builds as much as manually commenting-out code.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenCV library has several modules, you might consider leaving out modules like 'highgui' and 'gpu', and maybe more depending on what you need and don't need. Anyhow, I am not quite sure what you need. Maybe you should use a different smaller library instead, as reading, writing, decoding, converting, etc are not really Computer Vision operations, like a Hough transform or a distance map

One you might consider is cimg btw, you can easily strip that one down as it simply just defines more and more functions as part of the cimg class.

Good luck!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to disable modules?

Comment: If you build opencv from source, instead of installing if it using some other package manager (like apt-get), you can configure what modules to include using cmake. Since it is over a year ago I did this I forgot the details. However, I found that cmake-gui gave me a user-friendly interface to do so. Nevertheless, compiling your own libraries requires you to have some linux chest hair, so to speak. For a kick start look here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html. If there is no need for you to save kilobytes, use the package manger of your distro.

Comment: You can find a list of all the modules here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html . As I remember, you are also allowed to disable libraries for loading more exotic image formats and such. Here is an example of someone using cmake-gui to configure opencv: http://www.techunited.nl/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_Install_OpenCV . Good luck!